# Unfair usage of DRS

Tags: rules, cricket

I have a doubt regarding the usage of DRS. I have seen players make an appeal for DRS and then  the batsmen don't take any runs. So is it like the game stops as soon as an appeal DRS has been made? 

 If so then can it be misused in the following way?

It's the last ball of the game and batting team needs 2 runs to win. As soon the ball is bowled , the fielding team starts appealing for out and immediately the captain does for DRS( even though the batsman may be nowhere near out). The play would be stopped and thus, batting team would be denied an opportunity to win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is it like the game stops as soon as an appeal DRS has been made?

No. There is nothing in any of the ICC playing conditions which even imply this is the case - it's just like any other appeal in that the batsmen are free to run.

Given this, the rest of your question in obviously moot.

Comment: And besides that, an umpire where UDRS is available is very aware of the context of that ball, and will be especially attentive to any potential outs, and won't be moving for the review until they're satisfied play should stop.